# Charset problems in Entity Framework Core 3.12 Firebird.Core 7.10.1 while filtering or inserting

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

Is it possible to set charset for filtering, inserting in Entity Framework not changing database default charset

If I execute raw SQL, filtering works, but if I use objects, it fails if there are special characters.

Working

```
var sql = string.Format("SELECT * From Products p Where p.Name= '{0}'", productName);
var test = db.Products.FromSqlRaw(sql).FirstOrDefault();
```

Not working

```
var product = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name ==productName))
```

When defining charset in connection string it only works if reading data.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], including relevant DDL (with explicit character sets!). It sounds like your columns are character set `NONE`, which is something you shouldn't use. As an aside, changing the database default character set would have no effect. The database default character set only specifies the character set used when creating a column without an explicit character set.

Comment: the old thumb rule of SQL - don't use string splicing, use SQL Parameters instead.  https://www.bobby-tables.com

Comment: `only works if reading data` - your published here code does not do anything else, if the code never writes data then of course only reading would work. // Basically it seems to be about debugging your source data AND your predicate (filtering) function. Set a breakpoint inside the filtering function and check every row, how function calculates `True` or `False` and why it is doing so